# jQuery - How fix different events for multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am quite at the beginning of jQuery and therefore going through some exercises...but I am stuck with this problem of having two buttons in the DOM each being supposed to do different stuff, of course. However I am not able to find a way to attribute different actions. Can someone help, please???
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="content">
          <input type="text" class="my-input">

          <button class="set-button">Set</button>
          <button class="my-button">Add</button>
</div>
<h4>Output</h4>
<div id="output">
```

And this is what I have managed to do so far:

```
$('.content').click(function(){

   var $input = $(this).find('input')
   var input = $input.val();

   $('#output').text(input)
   console.log (input);        
   });
});
```

The problem obviously lies in the fact that I didn't call a particular button to read the input - I just couldn't figure out where to put the selector for the button or at least if I did the code didn't work anymore. Might seem silly, but I'm still learning.
Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ is a great place to start with learning about the library, how to use selectors, how to use event bindings, and much more.

Comment: shouldn't the click be on the buttons? why is it on the content

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
$('.content').click(function(){}
```

but the class `.content` is a wrapper.. it's wrapping the whole div
you should instead use the selectors in the button tag `set-button` and `my-button` wich will trigger the function after being clicked

now you have two differents classes so you should create two functions

```
$('.set-button').click(){/* logic */}
$('.my-button').click(/* logic */){}
```

is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

This maybe can help you. We create an eventlistener on the buttons.

$(this) - is the element we clicked. From this element we are searching the input field in the same parent. Save our value and append it into the target.

```js
$('.button-action').on('click', function(e) {
    // we prevent the standard behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    //we search in this context the input element to save the value
    var inputText = $(this).parent('.content').find('.my-input').val();
    // we save the target in Element in a value
    var $target = $('#output');

    // we ask what class the button has
    if($(this).hasClass('set-button')) {
        
        // we delete all child from target
        $target.empty();
        
        // we set the text of target with our input value
        $target.text(inputText);


    } else if($(this).hasClass('add-button')) {
        
        // we append the input value to the target
        $target.append(inputText);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
          <input type="text" class="my-input">

          <button class="button-action set-button">Set</button>
          <button class="button-action add-button">Add</button>
</div>
<h4>Output</h4>
<div id="output"></div>
```

We can use $('.button-acition).click(function() {}) too but this only works if the button is not inserted later into the dome by ajax  calls etc